# Passing and assigning functions versus calling them

Tags: javascript, function

I decided to post this question because I've followed several tutorials online & the treat this topic in different ways.
Let's say I've got a function to increment a counter:

```
function addCounter()
{
    counter++;
}
```

Now I want to call this function to put its value in other variable. Which of these ways is correct:
`var newcounter = addCounter();` or `var newcounter = addCounter;`?
Maybe it's a very basic question but, believe it or not, both methods gave me good results, that's why I want to know which is better, normal or, even better, correct!

Same with setTimeout: I've used `setTimeout(myFunction, 1000)` & `setTimeout('myFunction()', 1000)` with same results, so, which to use in this case?

Comment: I very much doubt that `var newcounter = addCounter();` gives the same result as `var newcounter = addCounter;`.

Answer (score 2):

`newcounter = addCounter();` and  `newcounter = addCounter;` should produce very different results.  I setup a [fiddle to show you the different return values](http://jsfiddle.net/7GQzn/2/).

**`newcounter = addCounter();`**

This assigns the return value of `addCounter` to `newCounter`.  The variable `counter` is incremented and nothing is returned.  Since `addCounter` returns nothing, `newcounter` has the value of `undefined`.  When I try to call `newCounter()` I get an obvious error.

**`newcounter = addCounter;`**

This assigns the function `addCounter` to `newCounter`.  Essentially, a pointer to a function is created and if you want to prove it, calling `newCounter.toString()` returns the function text of `addCounter`.

Calling `newCounter()` will execute `addCounter` and increment `counter`.

---

Like the previous two answers state, the string version of `setTimeout` is frowned upon.  You'd want to do the following to increment the counter every second.

```
setTimeout(addCounter, 1000);
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7GQzn/2/).

Comment: I know variable=function(); is correct, but, I'm using the other method with ajax & it works fine. I mean, instead of onreadystatechange=function(){...} I use onreadystatechange=ajaxReady with the function defined bellow & it works great without the parenthesys. In fact, the only place where I had problems using no parenthesys is in a function to obtein UTC, but the rest is defined without () & works, so, I'm driving crazy. But, as you say () are better, I'll use them from now on despite the other method works for the most part.

Answer (score 1):

It can't give you the same result. In first case, when you do `var newcounter = addCounter();` the newcounter variable will receive `undefined` value. Each function in JavaScript by default returns undefined except you provide some value by `return`. In second case `var newcounter = addCounter;` you insert into newcounter a reference to the function object addCounter. So from that step you just can call the same function by `newcounter()`.

When you come to setTimeout use, it will the same result because in first case you provide to setTimeout function a reference to myFunction and setTimeout will run it after specific timeout period. In second case you provide a string that will be evaluated like `eval` after timeout period. The reason that is not recommended to use a second case is because eval function is much slower and not so safety in some cases. 
Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)

Answer (score 0):

Neither. The function doesn't return anything, therefore assigning its return value won't do anything. Similarly, just assigning the function itself to the variable doesn't do anything either.

In the case of `setTimeout`, you should NEVER pass a string. You can either pass a function directly (`myFunction`) and it will be called, or you can pass an anonymous function (which makes it easier to pass arguments) such as `setTimeout(function() {doSomething(123);},1000);`

Comment: If I am correct, `var newcounter = addCounter;` will not execute the function actually. Rater it would assign the function to `newcounter` var. Is it?

Comment: Your answer is not right. A function that does not return a value returns undefined. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FFunctions_and_function_scope

Comment: @DimaKuzmich that's fine. Suppose it returns some value, then my understanding above is correct?

Comment: @Ali.NET my comment refers to the main answer. Your comment is exact.